# simplexml_load_file failed to open stream E_WARNING : type 2

Tags: php, xml

```
$song = "The Buzzcocks - Orgasm Addict";
$songeach = explode("-", $song);
$artist = trim($songeach[0]);
$song = trim($songeach[1]);
echo $artist;
             //echos 'The Buzzcocks'
echo $song;
             //echos 'Orgasm Addict'

$lyricxml1 = simplexml_load_file('http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyric?artist='.$artist.'&song='.$song.'');
$lyricchecksum2 = $lyricxml1->SearchLyricResult[0]->LyricChecksum;
$lyricid = $lyricxml1->SearchLyricResult[0]->LyricId;

echo $lyricchecksum2;
             //echos 'c58a88a5cd5550b2793a408d17193af6'
echo $lyricid;
             //echos '5497'
```

All good and proper so far.

But then once I get here

```
$lyricxml2 = simplexml_load_file('http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId='.$lyricid.'&lyricCheckSum='.$lyricchecksum2.'');
print_r($lyricxml2);
```

I receive this error:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- simplexml_load_file(http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId=5497&lyricCheckSum=c58a88a5cd5550b2793a408d17193af6): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! -- at line 15
E_WARNING : type 2 -- simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId=5497&lyricCheckSum=c58a88a5cd5550b2793a408d17193af6" -- at line 15
```

Even though the url/xml file is proper (works in browser manually)
http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId=5497&lyricCheckSum=c58a88a5cd5550b2793a408d17193af6

And is in the exact same format a $lyricxml1 (echo output: http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyric?artist=The Buzzcocks&song=Orgasm Addict)

Comment: Have you tried it multiple times and they all fail? Seems like the request just failed that one time. I copied your exact code and I am not able to reproduce any errors.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. When I run `simplexml_load_file(...)` with the 2nd url, everything works.

Comment: Hmm.. wow. Yeah I've tried like at least a dozen times on localhost and I also tried on phpfiddle.net and I always get the same error with the second xml file.  I will try on live host.

Comment: I also tried `file_get_contents($url)` to see the raw string without problem. To get to the specifics of the HTTP error, you may could use cURL to make a formal request and read the response headers.

Comment: also works fine on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `file_get_contents()` to load the file then use `simplexml_load_string()` to turn it into an object.

If you are loading a external file, like in your code example you can use curl to get the data, then convert it to an object using `simplexml_load_string()` on the response.